# Convert String to SomeType in Java

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, string-conversion

I have decided to write my own tiny ArgumentParser in Java,
the key point is it has method

```
public void addOption(String optionName, Class valueType, boolean required)
```

for doing something like

```
ArgumentParser parser = new ArgumentParser();
parser.addOption("--input_path", String.class, true);
Map<String, Object> options = parser.parse(args);  //args is String[]
String inputPath = (String)options.get("--input_path");  //hooray!
```

but i can't figure out how to attempt to convert String to some user-specified class automatically?
The code below obviously doesn't work

```
options.put(currentOption, registeredOptions.get(currentOption).valueOf(arg));
```

Is there some simple way to do that, which i can't figure out?
Or maybe you say that it is bad and vicious idea, i appreciate any advice!
Thank you!

Comment: `Class.forName(fullyQualifiedClassName);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several libraries doing this already, like [JCommander](http://jcommander.org/) and pretty much all of them use the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). That is, they allow clients to register converter objects that convert an input string into an object of a specific class. There are of course quite a few built-in converters too for the most obvious classes, like `Number`, `Boolean`, `File` or lists.

So you'll have something like this.

```
public interface Converter<T> {
   public T convert( String arg );
}

public class IntegerConverter implements Converter<Integer> {
   public Integer convert( String arg ) {
       return Integer.parseInt( arg );
   }
}
```

And in your `ArgumentParser` you'll keep a map of your registered converters and call the appropriate one.

Of course you can elaborate on this by specifying a hierarchy of converters to have more and less specific strategies but the general idea is the same.

Comment: Thank you for Java best (common) practices advice, i think I'll stick this course.

Answer (score 4):

You are basically aiming to create a function that will return an object whose class was passed as a parameter.

I know no general solution for this problem.

But there are some partial solutions that together, so I believe, will answer for what you are looking for:

**A.** Returned object is a **numeric**:

For int and float the solution is obvious:

```
int ival = Integer.parseInt(strParam);
float fval = Float.parseFloat(strParam);
```

**B.** Returned object class **has a string constructor** , i.e. a constructor receiving a single string parameter

That is:

```
parser.addOption("--input_path", MySpecialClass.class, true);
```

where:

```
class MySpecialClass {
     public MySpecialClass(String param)  // <----------- string constructor
}
```

Here you can use reflection to instantiate the required object by fetching and activating the constructor.
Note: our code does not need to know the return class identity, but weather or not it has a string constructor:

```
Constructor stringConstructor = classObject.getConstructor(new Class[]{String.class});
Object objectToReturn = stringConstructor.newInstance(stringParam);
```

Finally combining the above gives us an argument processing function similar to this:

```
Object processAnyParam(String strParam, Class returnClass, boolean mandatory) {

     if (returnClass.equals(int.class)) {
           return Integer.parseInt(strParam);
     }
     else if (returnClass.equals(float.class)) {
          return Float.parseFloat(strParam);
     }
     else if (maybe other numeric types here...) {
     }
     else {
          try { 
                Constructor stringConstructor = classObject.getConstructor(new Class[]{String.class});
          } catch (NoSuchMethodException  e) {
                // no string constructor; bail out..
                return  null;
          }
          return stringConstructor.newInstance(strParam);
     }


}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, there are many useful ideas, but biziclop's answer seemed to me the most simple and reliable. I think I will use some combined variant

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to convert without passing some method to convert the String to the right object type (assuming you don't require all classes to have a constructor with `String` as parameter that you want to use to parse the `String`). One possibility would be to pass [`Function<String, ?>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) objects to `addOption`, e.g.:

```
public void addOption(String optionName, Function<String, ?> valueConverter, boolean required)
```

```
parser.addOption("--stringParameter", Function.identity(), true); // remains identical
parser.addOption("--integerParameter", Integer::parseInt, true); // use Integer.parseInt(String)
parser.addOption("--binaryIntParameter", s->Integer.parseInt(s, 2), true); // integer given in binary format
parser.addOption("--fileParameter", s -> new File(s), true); // use File(String) constructor
```

Your parse function the code converting the String to the object would contain something like this:

```
Map<String, Object> result = //...
// ...
String key = //...
String stringValue = //...
Function<String, ?> converter = //... get the converter from where you stored it
result.put(key, converter.apply(stringValue));
//...
return result;
```

Comment: I wish i could use Java 8 with all its tasty benefits like lambda-functions =) Except explicit passing converters as lambdas, your idea is similar to biziclop's idea with converter registration as far as i understand